# Make Android activity wait for a class

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I have an activity and a Java class which I use to perform the connection with the DB and then read the response from a JSON. After reading the positive response I need to launch another activity.

Is there a way to wait until the end of the second class?

I tried to make the class extends AsyncTask and setting the variable which I return to the activity in the `onPostExecute` method, but it doesn't work.

**UserLogin (= Activity)**

```
public void OnLoginUtente(View view) {
    final String mailU = etMailU.getText().toString();
    final String pwU = etPasswordU.getText().toString();
    final String typeU = "Login Utente";

    DBConnection connection = new DBConnection(typeU, mailU, pwU, this);
    connection.doLogin();
    if(connection2.isSuccess()){
        //new actvity....
    }
}
```

**DBConnection (= Class)**

```
public class DBConnection{
private String type, email, password, URL;
private Context context;
private boolean success;

public DBConnection(String t, String e, String p, Context c) {
    type = t;
    email = e;
    password = p;
    context = c;
    if (type.equals("Login Utente"))
        //URL setting
    else if (type.equals("Login Pizzeria"))
        //URL setting
}

public void doLogin(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //read the response from the server
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject.getString("Status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (jsonObject.getString("Esito").equals("true")) {
                            success = true;
                        } else {
                            success = false;
                        }
                        
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("type", type);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}
```

}

Comment: *Make Android activity wait for a class* ... terrible idea ... it will block UI/main Thread

Comment: Not really, I assume he means ActivityA performs asynchronous task, while showing a cancel button and a progress indicator. When the task is done, launch ActivityB. A very common pattern. However, Jin, please provide more information, this seems like a common scenario and it's not clear what is "not working" here.

Comment: @Selvin Otherwise I have to write the exact same code for read the response from the server in another two activity. I thought a class could make it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the Intent of the second Activity in the `onResponse` callback

```
if (jsonObject.getString("Esito").equals("true")) {
   // intent to the second Activity
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify onResponse method as follows:

```
 public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //read the response from the server
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject.getString("Status"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (jsonObject.getString("Esito").equals("true")) {
                                success = true;
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                success = false;
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
```

Replace NewActivity with the name of activity to be launched.